# Add onFocus as well as background image to a view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` view to which I need to set the background image programmatically. However, when this view gets the focus, I need to show a stroke around it.

What am I doing:
The background resource (`view_onfocus_background.xml`) to show onFocus effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#F7CA18" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In the layout XML, I am adding the background as follows to apply the background with onFocus effect.:

```
android:background="@drawable/view_onfocus_background"
```

However, in the code, I have to set the different background image to the layout.

```
myLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_image);
```

So, obviously, the view_onfocus_background I added in the layout XML doesn't apply anymore!

Question:
How can I achieve onFocus effect as well as custom image background to the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that there is no way I can apply background effect through XML as well as the image background to the LinearLayout. The only thing I could do is to have two LinearLayouts (parent and child). Apply XML to the parent layout. Apply image background to the child layout. Add some padding in the parent layout to show the onFocus effect.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/customFocusLayout"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/view_onfocus_background"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/customTestLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- more stuff here-->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```